# Flexbox justify-content: space-around clickable area is content width only. Could it expand?

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to distribute menu items evenly, so use justify-content space-around. But clickable area is content width only.

If use **pure CSS** can expand clickable area? (Project will change menu content in the future.)

[image]

```css
.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.menu__link {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">ABC</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">DEFGHI</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">JKLMNOPQ</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">RSTUV</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">WXYZ</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another example.

```css
.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu__link {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu__link:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

.menu__item {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">ABC</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">DEFGHI</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">JKLMNOPQ</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">RSTUV</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">WXYZ</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Same as my answer, only have added some extra style for `menu__link`

Comment: I expanded from @Reginna's original code and obviously you did the same, so of course the code is going to look similar.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the code is that, youe `li` items are not fitting to the space of your `ul`

Just add `flex: 1; text-align: center;` to your `li` items to make the `li` items grow to the container dimension.

```css
.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.menu__link {
    display: block;
}

.menu__item {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">ABC</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">DEFGHI</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">JKLMNOPQ</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">RSTUV</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">WXYZ</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a padding to both `right` and `left` area of your `a` tag to expand it. I used `padding-inline` to add `2rem` to both. Or you can do it manually by using `padding: 0 2rem;`, either works. See the snippet below for your reference (added a `background-color` for you to see the area expanded clearly).

```css
.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.menu__link {
  display: block;
  padding-inline: 2rem;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">ABC</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">DEFGHI</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">JKLMNOPQ</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">RSTUV</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">WXYZ</a></li>
</ul>
```

Or as @Nitheesh answered, you can use `flex-grow: 1;` or `flex: 1;` for short to expand the `menu__item` to the available space equally, then add a `gap` property to the `parent` container if you want space in-between items. The advantage of this is that you'll have n equal containers.

Comment: Please donot update the answer with the code from an another answer to the same question. You have to present your own idea, and not make the solution general by covering code from other answers to same question. Downvoting because of that reason only. Seperate my answer from yours and I will revoke the dv.

Comment: I've removed the snippet, but it's not like the idea is original, I've also added a `gap` property, and `background` to clearly indicate the difference between 2 solutions.

Comment: Adding a `background` and `gap` to an existing solution will not make it your own solution. This is purely a css issue. Each person can have different idea to solve the problem in their own way. Its the choice of the asker to choose the solution apt to their scenario. Also its really bad to consolidate other persons finding in your answer and make the solution more general. This is a bad trend that is being followed in SO, users come with one answer and after some time they update answer by adding code from other answers and highiting the difference, Reverting the dv

Comment: I was not making it my own and I clearly tagged your name. I only posted the snippet for clear difference, now if you're going to insist that I made that as to do whatever it is you are thinking then you are free to think so. It just baffles me that you're making it like a million dollar question with no answer or reference elsewhere already. Is it any different from putting a `hover` effect on it? I think not. But to each their own.

Comment: Yet it is million dollar answer for me. Everyone is putting their own effort to prepare the solution, its really unfair to copy other answer to yours and make the answer look like a generic one that covers the benifits of other answer.

Comment: @Nitheesh. is edited this answer? because now this has not had any similarity with your answer.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi the similarity has been removed, and my downvote has been revoked.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi it was on the second part, I added a snippet with the same solution, but with the `gap` and `background` to clearly show the difference. It somehow offended Nitheesh even when it clearly mentioned and credited him for the solution. Never took the credit for his solution, only expanded on the explanation .

Comment: @Nitheesh Excellent:) Although copying from an answer is bad, sometimes occurs that is given multiple similar answers to a question synchronously. as that Jorge Z says.

Comment: @YongPin copying the code and marking the credits in the answer will never work. If you finds my anser is useful, you can upvote that rather than including that in your answer. If someone upvotes your answer thinking that this is a generic one, the upvote credit will only be added to your account, not to mine. I have seen ultiple ansers in SO where the user post one singl anwser and copy ever the other 5 ansers posted to the same question pointing out the benifits of that answer. Its a very bad trend and needs to be discouraged.

Comment: You have not copied my answer. Your current answer is your own code. There is no use for the name credits after including my code snippet in your answer. Even now you have mentioned modifications in my code in your answer. It was better if you added this as a comment to my answer.